# CSS Menu is too width

Tags: css, menu, width

I'm trying to make the red menu ends at the line of the eraser icon and still be responsive. It's ol element with float: left and position: fixed.
SCSS code:

```
    position: fixed;
    top: 74px;
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: $extendBarColor;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    > li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 7px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to reduce the size of the icons in the red menu if you want them all to fit on the same line.

Comment: What's the parent of this code? SCSS looks incomplete.

Comment: add your html code please

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)